# Carrot2 dcs php example class modification

Tags: solr, carrot2

I currently have solr and carrot2 configured and working on my server. I am using the dcs example class for php provided in the DCS download from project.carrot2.org . For reference the class can be found here https://github.com/amoghtolay/clustering/blob/master/carrot2-dcs-3.6.2/examples/php5/

I have tried a few things to modify the query to descending order and alter the number of records returned. The query used from a browser that give the results I need is `q=*:*&sort=_docid_%20desc&rows=20`. Although when I alter the query by altering the equivalent to line 35 in example.php found in link above to match the query I need I get the following error message "An error occurred during processing: HTTP error occurred, error code: 500" having the query only set to `*:*` works fine but it not the information needed. Also, source is set to solr.

Could anyone provide some assistance in getting this working, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to pass some extra parameters to the Solr request URL, you'll need need to append them to the [SolrDocumentSource.serviceUrlBase](http://doc.carrot2.org/#section.attribute.SolrDocumentSource.serviceUrlBase) attribute. You can specify the number of results using the [results](http://doc.carrot2.org/#section.attribute.solr.results) attribute.